# Convert.ToInt32 and int.Parse failing with single digit strings

Tags: c#, api, parsing, exception, int

I have an app in C# and I'm getting this exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo)
```

when trying any single digit string Convert.ToInt32

here's my code :

```
Console.Write("Enter IP : ");
string ip = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter port : ");
string port = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter interval in MS : ");
string temp1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
TO = Convert.ToInt32(temp1);
Console.Write("Enter number of threads to use : ");
string temp2 = Console.ReadLine();
threads = Convert.ToInt32(temp2);
ipe1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), Convert.ToInt32(port));
```

I have no clue what is happening so any advice would be helpful.
(I am posting this late at night so it may get removed and then re-asked at a better time)

Comment: Your code works for me... can you please highlight where it breaks exactly?

Comment: With correct entry that code works just fine. Check your user entry.

Comment: If you use a debugger, can you see the actual value that `Convert.ToInt32` is failing on?

Comment: Works perfectly for me as well.

Comment: You can ask anytime you want, `late at night` in your country but it's in the morning in my country :)

Answer (score 1):

found the solution: I had a thread reading keys in the background that was blocking the input :p, my bad

```
static void toggleloop()
        {
            do
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key1 = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.F1 && loop == true && showstatsbool == true)
                {
                    loop = false;
                    showstatsbool = false;
                }
            } while (true);
        }
```

should not be called until all forms of input are complete

Comment: Your problem is probably using `loop == true` and `showstatsbool == true`, useless comparisons and bad naming + wrong casing are messing the compiler up.

Answer (score 0):

this code will work if you enter `intiger` value as input.  even if you have space before or after your input integer value this will fail (try with `Convert.ToInt32(temp1.Trim())`). So you can call the [**`Int32.TryParse`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method instead. It returns a `Boolean` value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

```
int port;
IPAddress ip;

Console.Write("Enter IP : ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ip))
      Console.Write("The value must be IP Address, try again: ");

Console.Write("Enter port : ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out port))
      Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, try again: ");

string port = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter interval in MS : ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out TO))
      Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, try again: ");

Console.Write("Enter number of threads to use : ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out threads))
      Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, try again: ");

ipe1 = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
```